# pq-formula should return 2 values

Tags: c, formula

I have a problem and need some tips. I have written a function for the pq-formula and wanted to ask, how it's possible to return two values? And how can I insert an optional argument in my function? Like the square-root, which is not always needed? Here is my code. I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

```
double pqformula( int xSquare /*this one should be optional*/, int px, int q )
{
  q /= xSquare;
  if( px < 0 ) px *= -1;
  if( q < 0 ) px *= -1;
  px /= 2;
  double save = px * px;
  if( q < 0 ) save += q;
  if( q > 0 ) save -= q;
  double x1 = px + double( sqrt( save ) );
  double x2 = px - double( sqrt( save ) );
}
```

Comment: 1.) make the function return `double *` and return an array two reasults; 2.) generally there are no optional arguments in C functions; just pass 1 if you don't need `xSquare`

Answer (score 1):

Either return a pointer to an array of doubles, or add to extra double pointer arguments and pass pointers to double variables that the function can then store the results in.

And as @Ingo already commented: no optional parameters in C, here not a problem though as '1' will be a neutral value for xSquare.